# What strategy do you use to level up fast?

Tags: ingress

I am a Level 4 Ingress player. I live in a rural area, so it has taken a lot of driving and some time to get to that level. I have been concentrating on finding unclaimed portals and filling them up with resonators, linking ad creating fields. This works, but it is a slow process. I have attacked a few enemy portals and gotten some AP for that, but you seem to get less AP for destroying fields than creating them.

I see several people who have made it to level 8. Is there a better strategy to get more AP and level up faster?

Answer (score 7):

With limited portals, and limited portal turn-over (Little Rock, AR has a 3:1 resistance to enlightened active player ratio, turn-over here sucks), your best bet is to find a group of portals that are close to you, not used by other players often.

1. Make them the highest portals you can by yourself.
2. Get keys and connect them up in as many CFs (control Fields) as you can. The majority of your AP comes not from destruction, but construction.
3. Let them decay. It takes ten days for a portal to decay if it doesn't get a recharge.
4. Rinse and repeat.

This isn't the fastest way to level, but given the constraints of distance, gas, and lack of portals/competition, it is under those circumstances.

The fastest way, without these constraints, is to either connect up a lot of portals to create a lot of fields or to find an enemy portal with the most links and fields, and take it. The more links and fields, the more AP for you when you build/kill it.

Comment: This answer is right on for your situation. I personally level up using a nearby cluster of portals that are regularly controlled and heavily linked by the enemy. I'll go there every now and then just to destroy 2 or 3 portals with 5+ control fields each.

When you don't have this option, creating your own heavily linked cluster and letting it decay to create it again is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To level up you need portals, so you have two choices:

1. Move to a place where there are portals
2. [Submit new portals](http://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808254?hl=en)

Comment: -1 for the move to another place comment, +1 for submit new portals. The first was more facetious than helpful.